# Running multiple test cases with @pytest.fixture(params=) in Excel driven approach

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, parameters, pytest, fixtures

The below code runs the test once for each item in params. In this case since I used `[HomePageData.getTestData("Testcase1"), HomePageData.getTestData("Testcase2")])`

The `test_formSubmission` is running 2 times with data present in `Testcase1` and `Testcase2`.

But I want to run only one time in `test_formSubmission` with `Testcase1`.

I want to use `Testcase2` data in another `test_testcase2( )` which I will create.

So to conclude I use only one fixture mentioning all testcase names inside it and utilising different testcase data to different `test_tescase()`. How to achieve this?

```
import openpyxl


class HomePageData:

    test_HomePage_data = [{"firstname":"Rahul","lastname":"shetty","gender":"Male"}, {"firstname":"Anshika", "lastname":"shetty", "gender":"Female"}]

    @staticmethod
    def getTestData(test_case_name):
        Dict = {}
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\PythonDemo.xlsx")
        sheet = book.active
        for i in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):  # to get rows
            if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value == test_case_name:

                for j in range(2, sheet.max_column + 1):  # to get columns
                    # Dict["lastname"]="shetty
                    Dict[sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value
        return[Dict]
```

And I call it in below. Above give the data in a dictionary as list values.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest
from TestData.HomePageData import HomePageData
from pageObjects.HomePage import HomePage
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
class TestHomePage(BaseClass):
def test_formSubmission(self,getData):
 log = self.getLogger()
 homepage= HomePage(self.driver)
 log.info("first name is "+getData[0]["firstname"])
 homepage.getName().send_keys(getData[0]["firstname"])
 homepage.getEmail().send_keys(getData[0]["lastname"])
 homepage.getCheckBox().click()
self.selectOptionByText(homepage.getGender(), getData[0]["gender"])
 homepage.submitForm().click()
 alertText = homepage.getSuccessMessage().text
assert ("Success" in alertText)
self.driver.refresh()
@pytest.fixture(params=[HomePageData.getTestData("Testcase1"), HomePageData.getTestData("Testcase2")])
def getData(self, request):
print(request.param)
return request.param
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks halfter,I am so sorry to use those words.I am new to this forum,thats why i posted like this.Thanks for the advise.